# How to avoid connecting with wrong Access Points?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

Dear SuperUser experts,

We would like to ask for tech support on how to avoid machines connecting with wrong Access Points.
Here's the situation:

We have 2 AP and 2 rooms, one in Room A (AP-A) & one in Room B (AP-B), one switch, and one ISP Router (but the wifi is turned off already) . There are 2 glass doors separating the 2 rooms. Here's the problem, some machines in Room A are connecting to AP-B, and some in room B are connecting to AP-A.
So in short it's mixing up and the speed of the machines that are connected to opposite AP decreased.

How can we avoid this mixing up AP connection problem?

Thank you and looking forward to hear soon...

Comment: Why not just give the APs different SSID's and connect to the appropriate one per room?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect each machine manually to the correct Access points, if you can edit settings for multiple machines at once, you can save time by doing that.

Even better, connect the machines to a *wired* Network.

Also, A lot of advanced network configuration settings (on the computer end) are in the control panel. The fastest way to get to these settings is to right-click on the networking icon in the taskbar, click "Open Network and Internet Settings". After you have done that, the Settings app should open to the networks page. It should give you some options that might help you fix this.

In your situation, the easiest fix would be to Left-Click on the network icon in the taskbar, click on a wireless network, and turn off "Connect to this network Automatically" on all the networks you don't want that user connecting to. Also be sure to tell the computers to forget the other networks, as this will prevent accidental connections to the wrong networks.

If possible, you could set the network policy for the networks to only allow certain devices to connect to only the intended network for that device.

You can put the rooms on their own subnets, then configure the computers in each room to conect to the correct subnet.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response @Cyber_64 , I understand by using Wired Network, but this time, it's not possible because we need to change our seat plan... 
And I tried to look on the settings on how to fixed IP for this AP, but couldn't find.
Btw, the model of our AP is Aruba InstantOn AP12. Connected to our 24 Port Aruba InstantOn Switch

Comment: You're Welcome, There are a few quick fixes that can be implemented which I outlined in my answer, or will outline in edits. I hope my answer is helpful.